# Execute multiple query based on multiple condition in cypher / apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In cypher or APOC,  Is there a way to execute multiple query based on multiple condition.
I need something similar this APOC

```
CALL apoc.do.case([condition, query, condition, query, …​], elseQuery:'', 
params:{}) yield value
```

But here as soon as we met 1st true condition it skip all further condition and query. I want to execute all those query where my condition is true.

In simple word , I am looking for something similar to java case statement (without break; between case)

**Update**

I ran following query to use multiple apoc.do.when but it seems only my second apoc.do.when is not executing:

```
CREATE (y:EVENT { _id: 1, localComponentID:'l1', externalComponentID:'e1'}) with y 

call apoc.do.when(exists(y.localComponentID),"MATCH(e:EVENT) where 
e.localComponentID = lcl and e._id <> y._id with  y,e limit 1 create (y)-
[r:LOCAL_LINK]->(e)",'',{y:y,lcl:y.localComponentID}) YIELD value WITH value AS ignored, y

call apoc.do.when(exists(y.externalComponentID),"MATCH(e:EVENT) where 
e.externalComponentID = ext and e._id <> y._id with  y,e limit 1 create (y)-
[r:EXTERNAL_LINK]->(e)",'',{y:y, ext:y.externalComponentID}) YIELD value 
WITH value AS ignored return ignored
```

If I run above query two time with _id = 1 in first run and _id=2 in second run, I expect two EVENT connected with LOCAL_LINK and EXTERNAL_LINK. But I am only getting LOCAL_LINK between them not the EXTERNAL_LINK. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Note : I am using limit 1 because In case of multiple match I just want to create LINK with one node.

**Update 2**

Got it working , In my sample query I was that not returning y from first *apoc.do.when*

Here is the updated query which works:

```
CREATE (y:EVENT { _id: 1, localComponentID:'l1', externalComponentID:'e1'}) with y 

call apoc.do.when(exists(y.localComponentID),"MATCH(e:EVENT) where 
e.localComponentID = lcl and e._id <> y._id with  y,e limit 1 
create (y)-[r:LOCAL_LINK]->(e) RETURN y",'',
{y:y,lcl:y.localComponentID}) YIELD value WITH value AS ignored, y

call apoc.do.when(exists(y.externalComponentID),"MATCH(e:EVENT) where 
e.externalComponentID = ext and e._id <> y._id with  y,e limit 1 
create (y)-[r:EXTERNAL_LINK]->(e)",'',{y:y, ext:y.externalComponentID}) 
YIELD value 
WITH value AS ignored return ignored
```

Comment: Sounds useful, however there are some complications. We can return results easily from this procedure because only one query will be executed as a result. To support multiple queries executing, we'd likely have to restrict all queries to write-only.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And in my particular case all queries are write only query.

Comment: That could work. Can you add an issue with this request to the APOC GitHub?

Comment: created issue on apoc github https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/742

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the APOC function [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conditional_cypher_execution) for each condition/query pair (with an empty string as the `else` argument).

For example:

```
CALL apoc.do.when(<condition1>, <query1>, '', {}) YIELD value
WITH value AS ignored
CALL apoc.do.when(<condition2>, <query2>, '', {}) YIELD value
WITH value AS ignored
.
.
.
```

Since your comments indicate your queries are all write-only, the above example assigns the return `value`s to an `ignored` variable (that you can ignore).

Comment: That could work! And if the queries/conditions were provided in a list, you could match to whatever nodes were needed, unwind the list, and perform all of this with a single `apoc.do.when()`

Comment: @InverseFalcon Added example query with multiple apoc.do.when call but I am still not able to get it work.

Comment: @cybersam unfortunately no, I found out that in (update 2) if 1st apoc.do.when do not find match to create relationship then 2nd when condition do not work as well. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: not working.
returns error 
```
Variable `line` not defined (line 24, column 24 (offset: 934))
"call apoc.do.when(trim(line["4Z"])="1","merge (c)-[:USES_PRODUCT{date:line.CreateDt}]->(p4Z)",'',{line:line, c:c, p4Z:p4Z}) YIELD value WITH value AS  ignored2"
```

Comment: @umamahesh Is that your entire query? As the error states, that query does not define the `line` variable anywhere. If you need more help, then submit another question with complete details.

Comment: what i am doing is as below.
1st apoc.do.when happily consumes line, c but 2nd apoc.do.when can't see line, c and breaking the code
```
with line, c
call apoc.do.when (...) yield value as ignored1
call apoc.do.when (...) yield value as ignored 2
...

```